# How to change/set the resolution of a Linux agent in Azure DevOps

Tags: linux, azure-devops, resolution, agent

Our company recently decided to move most projects to Azure Devops.

The setup was smooth sailing for the most part, but now I'm encountering some issues I am unable to find an answer to.

I want to set the resolution of my Ubuntu 22.04 agent, however when searching the web I am consistently referred to the [`MS Screen Resolution Utility`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-autotest.screen-resolution-utility-task#overview).
As you can see on this page, this tool only works for Windows environments.

The whole setup is done using a YAML file.

My question is :

- How can I configure the resolution of my Ubuntu agent (using Yaml?) to a standard 1080 x 1920 ?

My worst case scenario, I will have to look at changing the OS from Ubuntu to a Windows env.

I tried:

- Using the Docker script to pass the resolution with xvfb:

> script: docker run -t --rm --shm-size=256m -v "$(pwd)":/tmp/project
> katalonstudio/katalon katalonc.sh -projectPath=/tmp/project
> --disable-gpu --init`**xvfb run -a -n 0 -s '-screen 0 1920x1080x24'**`-browserType="Chrome" -retryStrategy=failedExecutions -statusDelay=15
> -testSuitePath="Test Suites/OrganisatiePortaal/OP_BestuursEenhedenNIEUW" -apikey=xxx

- using the screen resolution utility to no avail (Windows only)
- searched google and stackoverflow for related questions, but I feel I'm missing something ? No results.
- Using a powershell task:

> - job: Build_Katalon
>   pool:
>   vmImage:  ubuntu-22.04
>
>   ```
>   steps:
>   - task: PowerShell@2
>     inputs:
>       script: Set-DisplayResolution -Width 1920 -Height 1080 -Force
>
>   - checkout: self
>     fetchDepth: 1
>     clean: true
>   ```

Currently I'm looking into using Bash to pass a parameter, but so far this is all new to me.

ps I'm sorry for the bad formatting